# Oracle 8g - How can i create a dynamic table without pivot?

Tags: oracle, pivot

i need to make a dynamic table in Oracle 8g, but this version doesn't have the `PIVOT` property. I want to create a table like this.

```
Date         | Code | count 
12/04/2016   |  a1  |  8
12/05/2016   |  a2  |  10
10/06/2016   |  a3  |  4
24/10/2016   |  a2  |  6

Date         | a1  |  a2 | a3
12/04/2016   |  8  |     |
12/05/2016   |     |  10 |
10/06/2016   |     |     |  4
24/10/2016   |     |  6  |
```

The numbers of codes is undefined. That would be the reason why i cant create a static table.

Comment: Please specify version number.

Comment: Preferably a real version number.... You'd struggle with pivot anyway if the number of codes is unknown. So you want a table (or just result set) that has an unknown number of columns? How will it be consumed? It might be something for a reporting layer to do for you instead.

Comment: I am just curious, how is it possible to run a 20 years old Oracle database release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a "plain" pivot query:

```
SELECT Date,
       max( CASE code WHEN 'a1' THEN count END ) As a1,
       max( CASE code WHEN 'a2' THEN count END ) As a2,
       max( CASE code WHEN 'a3' THEN count END ) As a3
FROM table
GROUP BY Date
```

PIVOT clause is only a syntactic sugar to make it easier to express the above query
The below query using PIVOT clause is the same as the above one.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT date, code, count FROM table )
PIVOT (
  max(  count ) FOR code IN ( 'a1' as a1, 'a2' as a2, 'a3' as a3 )
)
```

Comment: Oracle version is 8i(!) which is 20 years old. PIVOT was introduced in Oracle 11. I am not sure, perhaps even `CASE ... WHEN` was not available at 8i.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit CASE expresssions are much older that Oracle 8i (ANSII SQL 1992 - at least 25 years old), and 8i supported them, please check the documentation:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a85397/expressi.htm#1002628

Comment: looks like CASE was introduced in 8i (at least I did not find it in 7i) - so I wss not that wrong.